# Prove that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $p > 2$, then $x^2$ is not a primitive root

Tags: number-theory, modules

In order for $x^2$ to be primitive $\mod p$, it must have order $p-1$ and if $p>2$ then the smallest order it could have would be $2$ (when $p=3$). So $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^* = \{1, 2\}$ where $1$ has order $1$ and $2$ has order $2$.

$2^2= 4$ which is not in $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^*$ so cannot be primitive. From here I am not sure how to make a more  generalized statement to prove $x^2$ is not a primitive root. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$Z/p-\{0\}$ is a cyclic group of order the even number $p-1$. 
 ${x^2}^{{p-1}\over 2} = x^{p-1}=1$